# How can I improve Matlab perfomance for this code?

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop, combinations, allocation

**Adn** and **custo** are same size vectors, with a length of 10252 elements (length(Adn)=10252). Every row value in **custo** corresponds to the cost of the same row value in **Adn**. I'm trying to get the sum of all the possible combinations for the values in **Adn** and analyze the cost of that combination. From the Adn combinations, I am just interested in the ones that sum to a specific interval (which is lower than sum(A) and greater than sum(A)*0.9). **A** is previously written in the code, so it doesn't matter now. Then I want to store the **combinations** and their equivalent costs (**custoAll**) in two new vectors.

```
nA=numel(Adn);
for k1=1:nA
   B=combntns(Adn,k1);
   C=sum(B,2);          
   E=combntns(custo,k1);
   F=sum(E,2);
   D=find(((C<(sum(A)))&(C>(sum(A)*0.9))));
   if ~isempty(D)
       combinations=[combinations; B(D,:)];
       custoAll=[custoAll; F(D)];
   end          
end
```

This code is taking very long though.  I know I should preallocate the variables **combinations** and **custoAll** inside the loop otherwise it will change size in every iteration and take longer to run, but I haven't been able to find a good way to do it, since Adn is already so huge. Does anybody have an insight on this?

New explanation:

I am working with 15 impermeable areas in a lot, from which 7 can become the base of a permeable pavement. So first I took the sum of all the possible combinations of these 15 areas and paired each one of them with one of the 7 possible bases. But then I filtered this data, since I don't need all of them. I'm pairing the sums with the bases because I'm calculating the cost of the pavement for each new area that it would be responsible to absorb water from.

Adn has all these possible area sums (combinations from the 15). After filtering the data, considering only 3 of the possible bases and 47 elements for Adn, let's say:

```
Adn =

3.8825e+002
2.2850e+002
5.7470e+002
2.1700e+002
4.6175e+002
4.5025e+002
2.9050e+002
6.3670e+002
5.2375e+002
3.0675e+002
6.5295e+002
2.9525e+002
3.8825e+002
7.2645e+002
3.6875e+002
4.6175e+002
7.1495e+002
8.0795e+002
4.5025e+002
7.8845e+002
8.8145e+002
5.2375e+002
8.6995e+002
9.4345e+002
6.5295e+002
4.9320e+002
1.4746e+003
4.8170e+002
5.7470e+002
7.2645e+002
1.7079e+003
7.1495e+002
8.0795e+002
1.5481e+003
5.5520e+002
6.4820e+002
1.5366e+003
1.6296e+003
6.3670e+002
7.8845e+002
8.8145e+002
8.6995e+002
1.6101e+003
1.7031e+003
7.1020e+002 
1.6916e+003
9.4345e+002

bases = 

1.5500e+002
1.5500e+002
1.5500e+002
1.5500e+002
1.5500e+002 
1.5500e+002
1.5500e+002
1.5500e+002
1.5500e+002
2.3325e+002
2.3325e+002
2.3325e+002
2.3325e+002
2.3325e+002
2.3325e+002
2.3325e+002
2.3325e+002
2.3325e+002
2.3325e+002
2.3325e+002
2.3325e+002
2.3325e+002
2.3325e+002  
2.3325e+002
4.1970e+002 
4.1970e+002
4.1970e+002
4.1970e+002
4.1970e+002
4.1970e+002
4.1970e+002
4.1970e+002
4.1970e+002
4.1970e+002
4.1970e+002
4.1970e+002
4.1970e+002  
4.1970e+002
4.1970e+002
4.1970e+002
4.1970e+002
4.1970e+002 
4.1970e+002
4.1970e+002
4.1970e+002
4.1970e+002
4.1970e+002

custo =

3.3184e+002
1.5643e+002
5.7444e+002
1.4524e+002
4.2319e+002
4.0851e+002
2.2032e+002
6.6251e+002
5.0468e+002
1.8913e+002
5.5301e+002
1.7896e+002
2.6526e+002
6.4210e+002
2.4643e+002
3.3941e+002
6.2793e+002
7.4492e+002
3.2749e+002
7.1995e+002
8.4108e+002
4.0559e+002
8.2583e+002
9.2459e+002
5.3313e+002
3.5550e+002
1.6830e+003
3.4348e+002
4.4374e+002
6.2093e+002 
2.0652e+003
6.0696e+002
7.2232e+002
1.8012e+003 
4.2215e+002
5.2757e+002
1.7825e+003
1.9347e+003
5.1420e+002
6.9769e+002
8.1717e+002
8.0212e+002
1.9025e+003
2.0572e+003
6.0122e+002
2.0379e+003
8.9955e+002
```

`custo` gives me the cost of every pair of `Adn` and `base` (in other words, every possible pavement).

Now my problem: I would like to make new combinations of these pavements (so the bases should be unique in the combination). I'm interested in all the combinations of the pavements that their `Adn` values (areas) combined will sum to a specific interval. Let's say my interval is 3000 and 0.9*3000. Since I combined pavements, their cost will also sum. Then I want to get the combination that will cost less.

Comment: How do you plan to execute the line `B=combntns(Adn,k1);`. When k1 reaches 10, the no. of combinations ~ `3.5 * 10^33`. You have to rethink why you need to calculate it at all. Its impossible.

Comment: Actually, I just need the ones that sum to the specific interval, but I couldn't think of a way to find them before generating all the combinations first. =/

Comment: There is one very important rule with Matlab regarding all the performances issues: "never use loops". In most case you can find a way to do the same without loop.

Comment: How is `combinations` defined? Because in your if-case you use it to define itself. Also if I am not mistaken you want to find all the combinations of your array `Adn` (or to be more precise of the idx) which corresponding values in `custo` sum up to a value between `sum(A)` and `0.9*sum(A)`. If you construct all combinations first you have the problem of No. of entries. You would have to check 10252*10251*10250*... maybe you should look for another approach to your task.

Comment: Can you reduce this problem to (say) 5 elements. Also give the input and expected output. It will make the problem much easier to solve.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar 2 elements are around 10000^2 combinations (roughly) which is slightly more than 0.4Gb for doubles and about half the size for singles (internal order excluded). This is more or less how far it is possible to go since the next dimension will explode. I think OP must rethink the problem and see if another solution can be possible. An alternative could be to filter the problem.

Comment: @HelP I am afraid brute force is not possible here. I think a more sophisticated solution is required here, maybe you could explain the problem in a direct and compact form and we may be able to find an alternative methodology for you.

Comment: @HelP I tried a bit but you get quite easily a memory problem if you have to many possible combinations, which is easily the case if you use that many values and so many possible combinations. Would you mind posting the range of your values in `custo` and your computated value of `sum(A)`?

Comment: @coin what you are saying may be now be several years outdated ... please refer to [Matlab is no longer slow at for-loops](http://www.matlabtips.com/matlab-is-no-longer-slow-at-for-loops/)

Comment: @TheMinion sum(A)=6131.2 It's actually the `Adn`  combination that should sum to that interval, not `custo`.

Comment: @patrik Here's an explanation of my problem. I am working with 15 impermeable areas in a lot, from which 7 can become the base of a permeable pavement. So first I took the sum of all the possible combinations of these 15 areas and paired each one of them with one of the 7 possible bases. But then I filtered this data, since I don't need all of them. I'm pairing the sums with the bases because I'm calculating the cost of the pavement for each new area that it would be responsible to absorb water from.